# cant compile MK-Livestatus because of c++17

Tags: compiler-errors, ubuntu-16.04, c++17, nagios

I want to install MK-Livestatus Following [this insturctions](https://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_livestatus.html#H1:Remote%20access%20to%20Livestatus%20via%20SSH%20or%20xinetd) to connect t with nagios and thruk.

When I try to compile with ./configure && make
it says me:

```
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc-8... no
checking for clang-7... no
checking for gcc-7... no
checking for clang-6.0... no
checking for clang-5.0... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
...
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether g++ supports C++17 features by default... no
checking whether g++ supports C++17 features with -std=c++17... no
checking whether g++ supports C++17 features with +std=c++17... no
checking whether g++ supports C++17 features with -h std=c++17... no
checking whether g++ supports C++17 features with -std=c++1z... no
checking whether g++ supports C++17 features with +std=c++1z... no
checking whether g++ supports C++17 features with -h std=c++1z... no
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++17 language features is required.
```

I have searched how to compile this but I never found something what worked..

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/859256/how-to-install-gcc-7-or-clang-4-0

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to install gcc-7 or gcc-8. I solved this by building on Bionic instead of Xenial. To get gcc-7 on Xenial, run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7
gcc-7 --version
# The following commands make gcc7/g++7 the defaults.
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7 60
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 60
```

And that should get you past the error you're running into.